# Symfony ignore AppleDouble

Tags: php, symfony

I have a development server where I log in to (through ssh). Apple automatically creates the AppleDouble files/directories, which doesn't work well with Symfony. Every time I want to use a command (mostly doctrine:schema:update). I get AppleDouble errors about classes that don't exist.

Is there any way to tell Symfony to ignore those AppleDouble files?

I saw this issue on GitHub, but it's closed in favor of other issues, but I don't really know how to implement it. 
(https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5877)

Comment: Which Symfony version are you using?

Comment: @lxg I'm using 2.6.7

Answer (score 2):

Try to disable this in `OSX` itself:

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true
```

Found on [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5260367) thread.

Comment: OP of that thread already stated that he tried that command, but it isn't working. Unfortunately :(

Answer (score 2):

The folder is created not by Apple but by NAS which you are using probably. Look at this [FAQ](http://www.zeroonetwenty.com/blueharvest/frequently-asked-questions.html)

So if you use Netatalk you should probably look at its [docs](http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Special_Files_and_Folders). Same folders are created by [RedyNAS](https://community.netgear.com/t5/Legacy-NETGEAR-and-Partners-Add/Every-Folder-Has-An-quot-AppleDouble-quot-Folder-in-it/td-p/873376). But the common pattern as I understood is to run command from terminal that @Valentas described. And then remove the folders recursively.

If you have to hold folders and make Symfony work you should modify the value of `Finder::vcsPatterns`. As the property is static you can add the following code to the `app/console` (or `bin/console`):

```
...
Finder::addVCSPattern('.AppleDouble');
$kernel = new AppKernel($env, $debug);
...
```

Comment: Could you show the snippet? And also did you reload opcache?

Comment: same code as you supplied, only I added: `use Symfony\..\..\Finder`. How to reload the OPcache?

Comment: Just restart php5-fpm if you use so or apache. Or APC if you use it instead OPcache. OPcache is built-in for php from 5.5

Comment: Sorry, forgot that bug appears on console. This should be not cache but something else. Maybe register or something else. Can you play on local and check whether pattern in the list on when the finder is called in the `\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle::registerCommands`

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by your latest comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88472/discussion-between-origaminal-and-angelo-a).